# What is the function of も in this sentence?

Tags: particle-も

The folllowing sentence is an excerpt from the NHK easy article:

https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012832221000/k10012832221000.html

I've provided the preceding clause for more context.

「ヨコヅナイワシ」は、他の魚に食べられることがなくて、駿河湾の深い海にいる魚などの関係の中で、一番上の魚だということもわかりました。

研究グループは「ヨコヅナイワシ」が深い海の底の近くをゆっくり泳いでいる所**も**テレビに撮りました。

My understanding of も is that it is the non-logical reverse particle of は in the sense that it also marks the topic of the sentence, and states that whatever comments are made about the も topic are the same about the preceding topic. But the preceding topic in the 2nd clause is 研究のグループ?

I translated the sentence as:

The research group also took video footage of the location where the Yokozuna fish were swimming slowly, near the bottom of the deep sea.

This sentence sounds weird to me and I don't think I really grasp も (it's the particle I struggle with the most). Any suggestions?

Comment: In case you've missed it, this も has replaced を, not は.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, 「ところ」in this context doesn't mean "place" as you translate it. It means something to the effect of "matter" or "fact". [デジタル大辞泉（小学館） gives](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D/):

> 事柄。内容。こと。

To put it in English (borrowing from Jisho.org):

> thing; matter

And it is usually written in kana, not kanji, as seen in your source. I see in your transcription you put it in kanji 「所」, but the original text actually has「ところ」.

「も」tells us the thing mentioned was done in addition to something else. Set back into context, the meaning of the sentence becomes clear. What did the research group do besides shooting a video of the fish swimming? They caught four of them.

If you look at the original, pre-simplified report, this part is actually pretty unambiguous. (Just click on the[「普通のニュースを読む」](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20210125/k10012832221000.html)button at the bottom)

> また、研究グループは、深海に設置したカメラで、1メートルを超える「ヨコヅナイワシ」が、海底付近をゆっくりと泳ぐ姿の撮影にも成功しています。

A translation of the simplified sentence runs something like this:

> [In addition to catching four of them] The research group also shot a video of ヨコヅナイワシ swimming slowly near the bottom of the deep sea.

Comment: Hi Eddie, I appreciate the thought out response. However, on watching Cure Dolly's Organic Japanese episode on ところ, it appears ところ generally means some sort of place (physical, or metaphysical - a place in time). Thus, 話すところ　→ about to talk; 話しているところ　→ in the middle of talking; 話したところ　→ just talked. So in this instance, could the sentence possibly be saying "The research group also shot video footage of the fish in action/while they were swimming near the bottom of the deep sea". The translation is approximately the same in this instance, but I don't think ところ is functioning as a nominaliser?

Comment: Take「そういうところが嫌いだ」, you could understand ところ as a figurative place, but it's much more natural to translate it as something like "I dislike things like that (about you)". It is important to understand the phrase/sentence in context without binding oneself to dogmatic translation.

Comment: (typos fixed) I think if you interpret the nominalizer function as a way that ところ renders as a figurative place, it generally works perfectly. If you are familiar with こと、もの, you will see their usage is very similar to ところ. The differences you are talking about between those tensed phrases are the differences between the tenses themselves. ところ is not doing anything special, any more than こと、もの. The big difference in your sentence is between a *literal reading that interprets ところ as locational and physical* and *understanding it figuratively*.

Comment: I would argue「そういうところが嫌いだ」is still using ところ in the sense of place though (i.e. a part - I don't like the parts (of you) that are like that - in other words, I dislike things like that about you.

Comment: @LukeMcAloon And I agree with that. I didn't say it was incorrect. I said such interpretations/understandings usually work perfectly. That's why I am not sure where you disagree with me.

Comment: "The big difference in your sentence is between a literal reading that interprets ところ as locational and physical and understanding it figuratively." I understand what you're saying here - I guess it is not really necessary to translate ところ in the "swimming fish" example because there isn't much semantic difference between "fish that were mid swim" and "fish that are swimming" but I guess there are other cases where it can be translated more easily.

Comment: I suppose I am still learning and in the beginner stages I have found it beneficial to translate things more literally because I am trying to understand sentence structure etc. However thanks for mentioning dogmatic translation, I need to be more aware of that.